# Custom Font in DrawRect

Tags: objective-c, drawrect, uifont

I'm subclassing a UIButton and i want to draw text with a custom font.

I have added the font files to the p.list and to my bundle, but when the drawrect: method is called, the text is not drawn, i use

```
 NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:10.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color0, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle};

[@"FINISH WATCHING\n" drawInRect: textRect withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
```

If i use a system known font, it draws is with no problem.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, you *probably* don't need (or want) to draw the text with `drawInRect:withAttributes:`. Better, usually, to use the button's built-in label.

Comment: I have two elements in the button, i have an custom drawing and a text.. so the regular label will not help me..

Comment: Any one? I think I've tried everything

Comment: Have you hit all of [these steps](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)?

Comment: Yeah, when i user the "Roboto-Bold" font style outside the drawRect, it recognize it and i can use it in any lable...:/

Comment: Can you check that the return of `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:10.0]` is non-`nil`? I assume it is, if you use it elsewhere. And if you just change that font to a system font, it works?

Comment: Yeah it's not nil. I looped through all the fonts and printed them and i could see it. And yeah if i change it to a system font it works perfectly well.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure why this is happening. However, you can still use another `UILabel`; just add it as a subview to the button, and lay it out as you see fit. Then, put your text, with custom font, in that.

Comment: Yeah i guess I'll do this..although it is really strange...Any way thank you

Comment: It's less strange than you think. Generally, you want to avoid straight-up drawing strings unless you have no other choice, for performance reasons. Good luck.